# How to loop through first file and print each row in the first file next to all the rows in the second file using AWK?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

here's a  example of what I am trying to accomplish.

File 1:

```
Adam
John
Tim
```

File 2:

```
,2018-2-1301
,2018-3-1379
,2018-1-3809
,2018-2-5801
```

Output:

```
Adam,2018-2-1301
Adam,2018-3-1379
Adam,2018-1-3809
Adam,2018-2-5801
John,2018-2-1301
John,2018-3-1379
John,2018-1-3809
John,2018-2-5801
Tim,2018-2-1301
Tim,2018-3-1379
Tim,2018-1-3809
Tim,2018-2-5801
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the ordering of the output important?

Comment: Read 2nd file, save lines into an array, read 1st file and for each element of the array print line+element.

Comment: @Kusalananda - No, order really isn't that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { names[$1]; next }
                 { for (name in names) printf("%s%s\n", name, $0) }' file1 file2
Adam,2018-2-1301
Tim,2018-2-1301
John,2018-2-1301
Adam,2018-3-1379
Tim,2018-3-1379
John,2018-3-1379
Adam,2018-1-3809
Tim,2018-1-3809
John,2018-1-3809
Adam,2018-2-5801
Tim,2018-2-5801
John,2018-2-5801
```

This uses `awk` to read the first file (the file with the three names) into an associative array (as keys).  When it comes to reading the second file, each line of the second file outputted repeatedly together with each previously read name.

The `NR == FNR` test is true if we are reading from the first file. It tests the overall record number ("line number") with the record number in the current file.

---

You may also do a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) with GNU `join` like this:

```
$ join -j 99 -o1.1,2.1 file[12]
Adam ,2018-2-1301
Adam ,2018-3-1379
Adam ,2018-1-3809
Adam ,2018-2-5801
John ,2018-2-1301
John ,2018-3-1379
John ,2018-1-3809
John ,2018-2-5801
Tim ,2018-2-1301
Tim ,2018-3-1379
Tim ,2018-1-3809
Tim ,2018-2-5801
```

... where `99` is a non-existing field in either file.

In this example, the inserted spaces could be removed by piping the result through `tr -d ' '`.

Comment: have an upvote.. way better

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ cat names 
Adam
John
Tim

$ cat dates
,2018-2-1301
,2018-3-1379
,2018-1-3809
,2018-2-5801


$ while read name; do 
    while read date; do   
      n=`echo "$name" | awk '{print $1};'`
      d=`echo "$date" | awk '{print $1};'`
      echo "$n $d"
    done < dates
  done < names


Adam ,2018-2-1301
Adam ,2018-3-1379
Adam ,2018-1-3809
Adam ,2018-2-5801
John ,2018-2-1301
John ,2018-3-1379
John ,2018-1-3809
John ,2018-2-5801
Tim ,2018-2-1301
Tim ,2018-3-1379
Tim ,2018-1-3809
Tim ,2018-2-5801
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;b=NR;next}{for(i=1;i<=b;i++)print $0 a[i]}' File2 File1
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you preserve the order... with `gawk` you could even ditch the `b` and just use `i<=length(a)`...